# Need to render a jquery mapael map in a portal that is using Angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, mapael

Needed to render a  mapael map to plot points(based on city lat,longs)in a portal that is using Angularjs.  This is working fine if angular-route library is not used.   But as soon as the routes are configured, the map is not rendered.  It throws no error, but while debugging, I find that the class selector in the 'jquery.mapael.js' file is not returning the element.

The html snippet is as follows :

```
<div class="mapContainer" ng-show="isCurrentViewMap()">
                  <div class="map">Alternative content</div>
</div>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.4/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/india.js" charset="utf-8" ></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js" charset="utf-8" ></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mapael.js" charset="utf-8" ></script>    
<script src="js/mapConfig.js"></script>
```

The mapConfig.js is as follows :

```
$(function(){
        $(".mapContainer").mapael({
            map : {
                     // Set the name of the map to display
                     name : "india"
                    , defaultPlot : {
                        type: "circle",
                        size:5,
                        attrs : {
                            fill: "#000"
                            , opacity : 0.6
                        }
                        , text : {
                            attrs : {
                              fill : "#fff"
                            }
                            , attrsHover : {
                                fill : "#000"
                            }
                         }
                    }
                    , defaultArea: {
                        attrs : {
                            fill : "#fff"
                            , stroke: "#aaa"
                        }
                        , attrsHover : {
                            fill: "#fff"
                        }
                        , text : {
                            attrs : {
                                fill : "#000"
                            }
                            , attrsHover : {
                                fill : "#000"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },



                // Add some plots on the map
                plots : {

                    // Plot positioned by x and y instead of latitude, longitude
                    'Delhi' : {
                        latitude :28.613939, 
                        longitude: 77.209021,                                               
                        href:"NewFile.html",
                        text : {content : "Delhi"}

                    },

                }
            });
        });
```

I do get to see the Alternative content, but not the map.  Please help me with some pointers.